# What is the appropriate listener to use for Eclipse SWT Text?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have a class of this type `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text`. It lives inside of an eclipse plugin I am developing. I want to handle the event where the user selects text from within this field. That is... while focused, they click into some text and drag either left or right to select text. When this text is selected, that is when I need to fire my event.

I am yet unable to find the appropriate listener to cover my need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `SWT.MouseUp` is the event you are looking for. If you want to check "arrow keys and shift selection", listen to `SWT.KeyUp` as well and check the `keyCode` of the event:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setText("BLABLABLA");

    text.addListener(SWT.MouseUp, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            Text text = (Text) event.widget;

            String selection = text.getSelectionText();

            if(selection.length() > 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Selected text: " + selection);
            }
        }
    });

    text.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            Text text = (Text) event.widget;

            String selection = text.getSelectionText();

            if(selection.length() > 0 && event.keyCode == SWT.SHIFT)
            {
                System.out.println("Selected text: " + selection);
            }
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}
```

This code will only print the selection, if the user really selected something. If it's a mouse-up o key-up without selection, nothing will happen.

You might want to combine both in one listener to save space.

Comment: Oh, I realized that the user could also use the arrow keys + shift to select text. I think I know the right listener for that one though. Just wish eclipse had a premade one for select text.

Comment: @Zombies Then just add the same listener for `SWT.KeyUp`. No need to "unaccept" the answer.

Comment: @Zombies Edited answer. BTW: [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=354574&seqNum=3) is a list of all events you can listen to with a description.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the text selection you should consider using org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText. You need to register an selection listener. See below:

```
public void addSelectionListener(SelectionListener listener)
```

> Adds a selection listener. A Selection event is sent by the widget when the user changes the selection.
>   When widgetSelected is called, the event x and y fields contain the start and end caret indices of the selection. widgetDefaultSelected is not called for StyledTexts.

Comment: Nah brah. I tried this already and this is not applicable for selected text. Eclipse SWT has no event handler specially designed for selecting text.