# How to enable Next button in the wizardpage based on input- SWT Java

Tags: java, swt, jface, wizard

```
Boolean enablenext;
String name;
text = new Text(textbox1, SWT.SINGLE);

text.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            enableNext = true;
            getWizard().getContainer().updateButtons();
            name = text.getText();

        }
    });
```

I have a wizard with 2 wizard pages.
In the first page I have a Textfield.
I want to enable Next button in the wizard page based on the input of the text field. If we fill the textfield 'Next' button should be enabled and if it is erased 'Next' button should get disabled dynamically . This has to happen in runtime.
Could someone please help me how to do this using 'jface'.
Wizard page's Next button should get enabled on entering the input for the text field not just on focus of the text field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Appropriate Listener for SWT Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348411/appropriate-listener-for-swt-text)

Comment: that dint help me, it says about the enabling of button when text box if focused. but i want it when there is input given to the text field.

Comment: and it gave me this error , The method addListener(int, Listener) in the type Widget is not applicable for the arguments (new 
  Listener(){})
 - Listener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Just change the SWT.InFocus to SWT.KeyDown, here is another example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092889/what-is-the-appropriate-listener-to-use-for-eclipse-swt-text

Comment: But I'm unable to capture the complete data that i have entered in the text field

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: this.text.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {

   @Override
   public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.name = this.text.getText();
    this.enableNext = true;
    getWizard().getContainer().updateButtons();

   }
  });

Comment: name is a string field and is not getting filled

Comment: @liorsolomon : name field is not getting filled

Comment: Hi, @Lisha I really want to help but I'd appreciate if you could follow the website's best practice. Please submit the full code of your question. The snippet you provided doesn't tell the definition of the field text. Please submit the whole class so we can get a better understanding of what you are trying to do. Also, I suggest that when you submit a code sample use the code format - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: @liorsolomon : I have tried to format the code snippet , could you please check and help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the `WizardPage` `setPageComplete` method to enable / disable the next button:

```
setPageComplete(true or false);
```

`setPageComplete` will call the container `updateButtons` method so there is no need to do this.

You can call this time the text in the control changes. For a text control use the `addModifyListener` to listen to changes to the text and call `setPageComplete` as appropriate.

```
text.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent event)
    {
      // TODO get control text, save, and call setPageComplete
    }
  });
```

Comment: @greg-499 : thanks for the input. i want it this way .... As soon as i open the wizard , next button should be enabled if the textfield is filled with data or disabled if nothing is there in the text field. If there is nothing pre -populated in the text field, then once the user gives the input netx button should be enabled and the data user enters should be captured in a string field

Comment: So call setPageComplete true/false in the appropriate places.

Comment: Added outline of modify listener to answer

Comment: i added setpageComplete(true) inside modifyText method, but when i enter the data in textfield it is not enabling Next button of the wizard

Comment: I use similiar code all the time. Show us the code you are trying.

Comment: It works when i use update buttons. but not setPageComplete().

Comment: is there a way to capture or retrieve the complete text that has been entered in the text box. when i use getText(), im able to get the whole word except the last letter

Comment: In a modify listener getText should work fine - note that this is not the same as a key down listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can couple the button state with state of input field via notification listener:

```
textField.addModifyListener(e->buttonNext.setEnabled(textField.getText().length() > 0));
```

Here the whole sample code:

```
package dialog;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class CollobarationDialog extends Dialog {
    Text textField;
    Button buttonNext; 

  public CollobarationDialog(Shell parent) {
    super(parent);
  }

  public CollobarationDialog(Shell parent, int style) {
    super(parent, style);
  }


  private void openDialog() {
    Shell parent = getParent();
    final Shell shell =
      new Shell(parent, SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    shell.setText("Collobaration Dialog");

    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));

    textField = new Text(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);

    buttonNext = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    buttonNext.setText("Next");
    buttonNext.setEnabled(false);
    Button buttonCancel = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    buttonCancel.setText("Cancel");

    textField.addModifyListener(e->buttonNext.setEnabled(textField.getText().length() > 0)); 

    buttonCancel.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
             shell.dispose();

        }

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            // Nothing to do

        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    Display display = parent.getDisplay();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    CollobarationDialog dialog = new CollobarationDialog(shell);
    dialog.openDialog();        
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is about a JFace Wizard - this code is nothing to do with wizards.